# Why there is no sound on my Debian 7?

Tags: debian, audio, alsa

There is no sound on my Debian 7. How to set the sound properly now?

```
root@localhost:/home/debian# alsactl init    
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC887-VD"        "HDA:10ec0887,1458a002,00100302" "0x1458" "0xa002"      
Hardware is initialized using a generic method   
/usr/share/alsa/init/default:26: control element not found   
/usr/share/alsa/init/default:26: control element not found   
/usr/share/alsa/init/default:48: control element not found   
root@localhost:/home/debian# alsamixer   
cannot load mixer controls: Invalid argument
```

EDIT: The output of `alsa-info.sh` is [here](http://pastebin.com/WUGy4CDf).

EDIT 2: After adding the option snd-hda-intel model=generic to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, here's what I get:

```
root@localhost:/home/debian# alsactl init 
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC887-VD" "HDA:10ec0887,1458a002,00100302" "0x1458" "0xa002"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
/usr/share/alsa/init/default:26: control element not found
/usr/share/alsa/init/default:26: control element not found
/usr/share/alsa/init/default:48: control element not found
```

Comment: Try this http://alsa.opensrc.org/TroubleShooting ... have you found any errors using their checks?

Comment: Have you tried to add `options  snd-hda-intel model=generic` to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf?

Comment: Can you pastebin your "/usr/share/alsa/init/default" file content ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please try a more recent kernel.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to avoid pulsaudio?

Comment: Added instruction for backports kernel.

Comment: @YoMismo Why do you think he is not running PulseAudio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Try a newer kernel

You can get 3.16 from backports:

Add the line

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Then run

```
aptitude update
aptitude -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
```

and reboot.

### Debugging ALSA

Get the script

http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh

and run it to get information about your soundcard.

When you have more information about your soundcard, create the file

```
/etc/modprobe.d/mysound.conf
```

and add the options like this

```
options snd-hda-intel model=6stack-digout
```

Especially the model option is crucial, because obviously the generic method does not work.

A full list is in `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc-3.2/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz` in the package `linux-doc-3.2`.

Good luck! Soundproblems can be horrible to debug.

Comment: please to the txt at : http://pastebin.com/WUGy4CDf

Answer (score 0):

Debian 7 "wheezy" was released in may 2013, with a kernel released early 2012. If your sound hardware is more recent than that, it is possible that it just isn't supported by Debian 7.

Have you tried with Debian 8 "Jessie"?

Comment: no ,my sound card is older than 2010.